# Yii2 Masked Input Widget can't publish file jquery.inputmask.bundle.js

Tags: yii2, input-mask

I recently deleted my entire vendor folder, made some adjustments to my composer.json file (packages upgrades) and then execute composer install. Was trying to make sure no obsolete package was left behind.

The `MaskedInputAsset.php` file from the Masked Input Widget that comes with the Yii 2 framework tries to publish and load `jquery.inputmask.bundle.js` but the file doesn't exists in `vendor/bower-asset/inputmask/dist` folder.

The version of inputmask installed is 5.0.9 and I checked the repository on Github. There is no file called `jquery.inputmask.bundle.js` in the `dist` folder.

Maybe it's time to an update to `MaskedInputAsset.php`?

To try to solve it I manually edited my local copy of `MaskedInputAsset.php` and changed

```
public $js = ['jquery.inputmask.bundle.js'];
```

to

```
public $js = ['jquery.inputmask.min.js'];
```

and then the correct file was loaded in the browser and the widget worked.

I'm on version 5.0.9 of inputmask and 2.0.49.2 of Yii.

I have no direct dependency of inputmask on my composer.json file so it's installed by Yii (probably).

Anyone faced this already? What else should I check before create a pull request in the Yii2 Github project? I mean, I'm trying to make sure a PR is needed to solve this and that I'm not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that, it was overlooked on the release, and it's fixed on master already. Please use master version or, like you already did, create your own Asset class.

Comment: No problem @Bizley! Thanks for fixing it already. As a suggestion, shouldn't it be better to publish the minified version of jquery.inputmask.js? it's 100 Kb against 200 Kb of the not minified version.

Comment: True, I guess it should be minified for sure on the production env.

Comment: So why not make `MaskedInputAsset.php` to publish the minified version that's already in the `dist` folder? What I'm not seeing here?